# Motorola 68k: Understanding the status registrer flag states

Tags: motorola, 68000, bitflags, status-register

I'm having trouble understanding how exactly the Status Register (SR) content works.

[image]

Let's say that the content of (SR) = $0300. How would I figure out in which states the flags are?
Of course that would also answer the question, if the flags are in [insert states here], (SR) = $????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the SR contents to binary, write it next to the boxes:

Most of the bits are just flags and signal a yes/no condition, except the Interrupt Priority Mask, which actually is a number between 0 and 7.

$0300 = 0b0000001100000000

**<s>T</s>0<s>S</s>003000<s>XNZVC</s>**

meaning

- No Trace mode
- No Supervisor mode
- Interrupt priority level: 3
- No extent, negative, zero, overflow or carry condition

Comment: Yeah, stupid me thought so but the paranoid me was looking for a catch. So basically reading the nibble as binary and converting it to hex ($0300 means I0 and I1 are set to one cause 0011 =3)